# Joining Rows To Avoid Redundancy in Mysql Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have 2 tables:

Table1: **product**(id_product, ...)

Table2: **image_product**(id_image, id_product).

In table 2, we can find that there are many images belong to one single product meaning that we can have many **id_image** values for the same **id_product** value.

What I want to do is to join both tables; However, **Table01** contains a lot of data, and to join it with **Table02** will cause a lot of redundancy depending on how many images for each product which i think it's not a good practice. So I  want to ask if there is a way to join both tables in a way where in one column there is the **id_product** and in the next column there is a list of all the id_image that belong to that product id.

Comment: The premise of the question is flawed

Comment: @alladin , my answer is helpful to you?

Comment: @chiragpatel yup.. exactly what i wanted.. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use group_concat for this problem.

[Click Here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) to understand group_concat with example.